# Compiling issue with VS2010 and boost::posix_time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

I've run into a problem driving me mad. I've implemented a timer using the followin timer entry construct:

```
typedef std::multimap<boost::posix_time::ptime, events::ITimeout*> TEntryMap;
TEntryMap entries_;
```

and I insert elements into the multimap with:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime tTimeout = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(timeout);
entries_.insert(std::make_pair(tTimeout, ptr)); // ptr is the events::ITimeout object
```

and in one translation unit (cpp file) it works perfectly. However, now I need to move this functionality to another cpp file, and now I get a compilation error:

```
1>Build started 2013-02-07 15:38:18.
1>ClCompile:
1>  EventDispatcher.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(260): error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const boost::posix_time::ptime' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          ....\boost\boost\date_time\posix_time\ptime.hpp(57): could be 'boost::posix_time::ptime &boost::posix_time::ptime::operator =(const boost::posix_time::ptime &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const boost::posix_time::ptime, const boost::posix_time::ptime)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(259) : while compiling class template member function 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::operator =(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const boost::posix_time::ptime,
1>              _Ty2=events::ITimeout *
1>          ]
1>          ....\eventdispatcher.cpp(72) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const boost::posix_time::ptime,
1>              _Ty2=events::ITimeout *
1>          ]
1>
```

I'm clueless and been struggling with this for 2 hours. I see no difference between the working implementation, and the non-working one. The same construct, same multimap, same includes, same everything! ;(

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem, and it smells like a VS2010 C++ compiler bug (when using std::remove_if). In a function implementation later on in the class using the construct, I tried to remove elements in the map with:

```
void removeEntry(events::ITimeout* p)
{
    std::remove_if(entries_.begin(), entries_.end(),
        [&](TEntryMap::value_type& entry)->bool
        { 
             return (entry.second == p);
        }
    );
}
```

Changing that code to:

```
void removeEntry(events::ITimeout* p)
{
    TEntryMap::iterator it = std::find_if(entries_.begin(), entries_.end(),
        [&](TEntryMap::value_type& entry)->bool
        { 
             return (entry.second == p);
        }
    );
    if (it != entries_.end()) entries_.erase(it);
}
```

makes the insertion code work. Go figure. Note that even if I use a struct based predicate instead of a lambda closure, it still doesn't work with std::remove_if...